# How to change directory (outside directory i.e. desktop) of file system in node.js

Tags: node.js

Hello I'm having difficulties in creating files in nodejs, when i try to create a file it only creates within the folder of my program. For example, I created test.txt then it will create on the program folder. what i want is to create a file outside the program folder. For example, I wanted to create test.text on desktop. is it possible?

I am using this:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the absolute path (`/dir1/dir2/test.txt`) rather than the relative path (`dir1/test.txt`).

Comment: i'd like to point out - it is not really recommended to create files like that.  Be considerate of the account running your application AND what else it has permissions to...

Comment: @akaphenom the purpose of doing this is to have auto-back up of files. is it still not recommended? or should i think another solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe if the purpose of this is to have backup of files, then you should rather run a basic script which will dump your files from your program location. You could always schedule it based on your choice of frequency.
It would be a much better approach instead of going out of your program folder just to create files. Not recommended!

Comment: Just listened to you. i only used auto-backup on sql @akaphenom

Comment: don't know what the preferred protocol is, but I would suggest either posting your own answer and accepting it.  BIUT make sure your question is very explicit... OR deleting this question (if in hindsight it was a standard answer not related to the gist of your original question)